# SwiftUI TabView on WatchOS breaks when a ScrollView is nested inside. SwiftUI bug or coding error?

Tags: watchos, swiftui

So I've noticed that TabView loses horizontal swiping between tabs when any type of ScrollView is nested inside. This includes ScrollView and List. Wondering if this is a bug I can just wait for a fix or if I'm making a mistake in my code. Any insight is appreciated.

This code works as expected:

```
TabView {
  Text("Tab 1")
  Text("Tab 2")
}
```

This code will freeze on "Tab 1" and horizontal swiping between tabs doesn't work:

```
TabView {
  ScrollView {
    Text("Tab 1")
  }
  Text("Tab 2")
}
```

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12 / watchOS 7, SwiftUI Life-cycle.

Comment: This actually appears fixed with Xcode 12 beta 3. I believe this was a bug in Xcode 12 beta 2